# Want a cache filter attribute that keep data in cache till user logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want a write filter that attribute that keep data in cache till user logged in.
I have a user image that can be seen by user.
I am accessing the image from cache.
Now if user image update the image still he can see old image that is fine as i am taking image from cache.
But when user log out and then log in still he can see old image as the reason is i am accessing data from cache.
I want user should see updated image if he log out and then log in, and i have use cache for it.
how to write cache filter attribute for it.

Comment: Just update the cache image when the user updates the image, or use different image URLs for guests and authenticated users. A cache *filter* works on requests, it can't know the user's history.

Comment: I am clearing image with HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/User/DownloadUserPicture"); on update of image but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem` should work unless you are using `querystring` or additional route parameters.

You can always use `VaryByCustom`to make sure cache holds only for a duration of a session but you have to make sure you clear the session once user is logged out.

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{ 
  ... 
 public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
 {

    if (custom == "session") return context.Session.SessionID;

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
 }
```

and then decorate your action with parameter:

```
public  class UserController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByCustom = "session")]
    public virtual FileContentResult UserImage()
    {
```

Few things - you have to make sure that `SessionId` gets renewed when user logs in and abandoned when he logs out. Not sure what authentication provider you are using it's also worth putting something in to session when user logs in to avoid `SessionId` being changed

`SessionId` is just an example you can replace it with authentication token (if you have one) or anything else which holds its value through the time user is authenticated

Comment: It goes to your Global.asax.cs, I've edited the answer.

Comment: can give me enter solution i.e controller , action filter code

Comment: See my edit. Two changes only - override `GetVaryByCustomString` and decorate your controller's action (download image) with output cache attribute with ` VaryByCustom = "session"` and that is it.

Comment: Have a look at this http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/

Comment: [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "session")]
  public ActionResult DownloadUserPicture(Guid id, string modifiedDate, string session)     html src=@Url.Action("DownloadUserPicture", "User", new { id = contextInfo.UserId, modifiedDate = "10/11/2014", session = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID})    this doesn't works for me

Comment: I fixed wrong parameter in the answer should be `VaryByCustom = "session" ` instead of `VaryByParam = "session"`, you don't need seesion parameter in your method.
        [OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByCustom = "session")]
        public ActionResult DownloadUserPicture(Guid id, string modifiedDate)

and then in code 

@Url.Action(
            "DownloadUserPicture",
            "User",
            new { id = contextInfo.UserId, modifiedDate = "10/11/2014"}
btw what is modified date?

Comment: i solve this issue by passing lastModified parameter to method,  now i am passing lastModified paramter to action, in this case when somebody navigate through UI action result comes from cache and when user press F5 he get result from server.  Can you tell me reason behind it